# How to create a function that grows up to a certain point and finishes in 1?

Tags: functions, approximation

I want to create an easing function $f(x,h)$ that looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to grow fast (so that $f(x,h) = h$ when $x$ is around $0.3$ and then it can fall slowly until $f(1,h) = 1$ (whatever $h$ is).

How can I build such function? I've been trying to approximate some functions but I cannot think of a way to build this without using recursion and splitting the function in subfunctions for $x \le 0.3$ and $x > 0.3$.

Comment: From the picture, I'm assuming we can assume $h \gt 1$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC yes, you can assume that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that when you say "easing function", you mean "the simplest possible". Assuming a maximum at $0.3$, a nice function with few terms that I could find is by imposing
$$\begin{cases}
f'(0.3)=0 \\
f(1)=1 \\
f'(1)=0
\end{cases}$$
in the function $y=e^{ax^2+bx+c}x^d$. In this way you will find
$$y=x^{\frac{3}{5}a}e^{ax^2-\frac{13}{5}ax+\frac{8}{5}a}$$
and the relation between your $h$ and $a$ is
$$(\frac{3}{10})^{\frac{3}{5}a}e^{\frac{91}{100}a}=h$$

Comment: With easing functions, I mean [this](https://easings.net/#).

Comment: That's a nice looking candidate, but I will mention that $f'(1)$ doesn't look to be $0$ in that image.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, there was an "a" missing.

Comment: @Daniel I had read some texts on the subject and looks like this function gives what you want.